# Trouble uploading info to Parse and performing segue with the same IBAction button

Tags: ios, segue, parse-platform, ibaction

I call this method:

```
  - (IBAction)createGroup:(id)sender {
    PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Messages"];
    [message setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
    [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.message = message;
        }
    }];
 }
```

When I run that by itself, it runs fine and the data class is created on Parse. But when I add a segue to the same button, it performs the segue and does not create the class on Parse. What can I do to make the same IBAction button create the class on Parse BEFORE it performs the segue?

Comment: Like the answer said, use the segue instead of the IBAction (so remove the connection to the createGroup action), and implement prepareForSegue. You need to remove the IBAction connection so that you don't get 2 events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement prepareForSegue: in your view controller. This gets called before a segue is fired.

In your view controller, it should look like

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegueIdentifier"]) {
        [self createGroup:nil];
    }
}
```

If the button is firing a segue in storyboard, this will get called right before it performs the segue.

Comment: I've tried that, no use :( been stuck on this since 9am this morning. So frustrated.

Comment: I added sample code of the implementation of prepareForSegue.  This will definitely call this code before it performs the segue - how have you tried it, and how did it not work?  Implement the prepareForSegue method and put a breakpoint in it and tap your button - step through and verify that its calling prepareForSegue, and that prepareForSegue is then calling createGroup: